# Dropdown doesn't select value from model in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select element, which renders a list of objects, nothing spectacular.

```
<select ng-model="defaultObject" ng-options="obj.description for obj in allObjects">
</select>
```

which generates:

```
<select ng-model="defaultObject" ng-options="obj.description for obj in allObjects">
            <option value="?" selected="selected" label=""></option>
            <option value="0" label="Value 1">Value1</option>
</select>
```

and it looks fine. It generates first empty option because at the time of rendering `allObjects` isn't created yet, so that's expected.

However, the problem is that when `defaultObject` model is set to an object that represents second option inside the select element(`Value1`), select element doesn't update selected option, everything looks the same. It's like a 1-way binding, `defaultObject` model can be set from a dropdown, but updating `defaultObject` doesn't update the dropdown to select that element.  Could this be fixed ?

Comment: `$scope.defaultObject = $scope.allObjects[0]` if the model is an object you should pass it by reference

Comment: You have a small mistake here: `obj.description for object`: `obj` and `object` should be the same name.

Comment: yeah, it is just a typo, i renamed real names

Comment: bind defaultObject to $scope in controller ...

Comment: @Zed: Excellent. Please have a look at my answer, I've got a couple of options available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that angular appears to use `==` to check what item in the array has been selected. In JavaScript, two objects that contain the same data are still not the same objects, they're references to different objects:

```
{a: 1} == {a: 1} // false
```

The easiest solution is to set your model to an item from the array manually, in your controller:

```
$scope.defaultObject = $scope.allObjects[0];
// (Or some other index that exists in the array)
```

---

Another option would be to bind the `<select>` to a specific value in the objects, instead of to the object itself:

```
<select
    ng-model="defaultObject"
    ng-options="obj.id as obj.description for obj in allObjects">
</select> <!--       ^ bound value,   ^ display value -->
```

This will result in the selected `obj`'s `id` being stored in `$scope.defaultObject`, and on page load, the `obj` with the `id` that's set in `$scope.defaultObject` will be selected.

The disadvantage here is that your model doesn't contain the complete selected object, only it's `id` property.

Comment: What you mean by `obj.id as obj.description`? where you declared `obj`?

Comment: @RameshRajendran: Typo, copied from the OP, but it's fixed now. So, is there anything actually _wrong_ with my answer? If so, I'd like to learn from it.

Comment: So, now I tried with your first approach, and $scope.defaultObject == $scope.allObjects[1] is true, however dropdown still isn't updated. Where should I look next ?

Comment: Does `$scope.allObjects[1]` exist, or is it `undefined`?

Comment: @Cerbrus Sorry, your approach actually works, it was just that part of my code changed defaultObject after it was set to a value from array. I just expected that Angular is smarter than this.

Comment: @Zed: I'm sure they'll work on objects in selects, eventually. Angular is still quite young. ;-) It's one of the few use cases that I know of that requires a manual "intervention" like that, though.

Comment: It seems that Angular already provides a better solution. I changed my code to this ng-options="obj.id as obj.description for obj in allObjects track by obj.description" and it works without any hacks, it simply uses description property for comparison.

Comment: But can 2 objects possibly contain the same description?

Answer (score -1):

Your code is wrong , please try this code instead of your code (change obj to object in the ng-option )

```
<select ng-model="defaultObject" ng-options="object.description for object 
in allObjects"> 
<option ng-if="!defaultObject" value="">Select Object</option>
</select>
```

You need add only one option for default select.

Comment: This answer doesn't work. If a `defaultObject` is set, the select will still not select the right item, for reasons I explained in my answer.